# Disable Apache http2 announce via htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, header, upgrade, http2

I have a website on a shared host, responding with these HTTP headers on each page request:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 21 Sep 2017 14:34:46 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.31
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Upgrade: h2,h2c
Connection: Upgrade, Keep-Alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=400
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

As you note, there is the `Upgrade` header that is an announce from Apache about the support of HTTP2 protocol.

For some reason, I need to disable this behavior of Apache, in order to send responses without the `Upgrade` header.

Who knows how to disable it from the .htaccess file?
I've already found this solution:

```
Header unset Upgrade
```

But it's not the good one, since sometimes I need to output a custom `Upgrade` header from my code (needed to broadcast a firmware upgrade to some thermal printer devices).

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try turning it off with this config: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_http2.html#h2upgrade.

Alternatively, for a .htaccess only solution, use the `Header edit` functionality:

```
Header edit Upgrade (.*)h2,h2c(.*) "$1$2"
```

Note this may leave you with an empty upgrade header, and you may have to change the config depending on what exactly is shown by your server (e.g. extra commas).

Comment: The matter is that i cannot edit the general Apache config since i'm on a shared host. I was wondering if there's something to do within the httpaccess file.

Comment: Edited my answer to show how to edit the Header (which is allowed in .htaccess files).