# http to https redirect via application load balancer not working in iphone safari

Tags: redirect, https, mobile-safari, aws-application-load-balancer

We are doing a redirect from http to https on our AWS application load balancer that works great in most browsers, but doesn't work in safari in an iphone.  The redirect is implemented as outlined here https://www.fischco.org/technica/2018/aws-alb-redirects/

In safari, our site works perfectly in an iphone when you load it via https, but when you don't include a protocol or use http, it says "Safari could not open the page because the server stopped responding."

Any ideas on how to fix this without doing client-side redirection?

Comment: Could you please add output from the development console? Also, does this problem reproduce if you are using Chrome's iPhone emulation?

Comment: The problem doesn't reproduce in Chrome's iPhone emulation.  Is there a development console in the iphone?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an Apache bug (https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59311), for which a solution can be found here: https://serverfault.com/questions/937253/https-doesnt-work-with-safari (check out Steffen Ullrich's answer and the comments)

**TL;DR;**

Add this to your host config

```
Header unset Upgrade
```

OR alternatively, add this to your .htaccess file (see [Disable Apache http2 announce via htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46495192/disable-apache-http2-announce-via-htaccess))

```
Header edit Upgrade (.*)h2,h2c(.*) "$1$2"
```

Comment: The site uses Tomcat with no Apache.