# HTTP416 with Laravel/Excel

Tags: php, laravel, http2, nginx-config, laravel-excel

Since my hosting provider has switched to HTTP2 I am getting a `HTTP 416 Range Not Satisfiable` error when trying to export data to Excel OR pdf formats. What I've tried already:

- adding `RequestHeader unset Range` to .htaccess
- adding `Header unset Accept-Range` to .htaccess
- setting Cache-Control headers expiration to 0

I've talked to the technical support of my hosting provider and whatever they've doing for the next 20 minutes didn't work either. I think they even tried to switch off HTTP2 for my account – however the error persisted.

What I find even more bizarre is the fact that the error comes before the logs have been written, meaning that the file has not been generated at that point at all. It seems like the request comes to the server and bounces back with 416 without actually launching any process in the first place. Any ideas what it could be? I have not touched the code in the last 2 weeks and it seems to have been working alright.

Here are the request headers

```
:authority: [....xxx].com
:method: POST
:path: /v1/reports/shifts/export
:scheme: https
accept: application/json
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9,de;q=0.8,ru;q=0.7,be;q=0.6,pl;q=0.5,fr;q=0.4
authorization: Bearer: eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGc....
cache-control: no-cache
content-length: 132
content-type: application/json
origin: https://[....xxx].com
pragma: no-cache
referer: https://[....xxx].com
sec-ch-ua: " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="101", "Google Chrome";v="101"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "macOS"
sec-fetch-dest: empty
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-site: same-site
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.64 Safari/537.36
```

and here are the headers coming back with HTTP416 response

```
accept-ranges: none
access-control-allow-headers: Origin,X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Accept,Authorization,Accept-Language,Content-Language,Last-Event-ID,X-HTTP-Method-Override
access-control-allow-methods: GET, PATCH, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
access-control-allow-origin: https://[....xxx].com
access-control-request-headers: X-Requested-With
cache-control: public
content-disposition: attachment; filename=shift.xls
content-length: 0
content-range: bytes */6144
content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel
date: Fri, 27 May 2022 11:54:20 GMT
last-modified: Fri, 27 May 2022 11:54:20 GMT
server: nginx
vary: Authorization
```

Any ideas?

Comment: For some reason you have `content-length: 0` and `content-range: bytes */6144` which basically says your content is 0 bytes long but your response contains 6144 bytes of content. The question is who is setting the content-length header, usually it's calculated and set by the web app (in this case I guess Laravel)

Comment: I see it, too. Getting this inconsistency solved could actually solve the whole thing. No CORS or CSP specific errors are getting logged either, so we can probably exclude those. What could it be then?

Comment: What is your setup here? You said your hosting provider switched to http/2 but you also mention nginx config which might indicate you have some control over the webserver i.e. you can disable http/2 if it's causing problems?

Comment: It's nginx, yes, running Laravel/PHP. I can edit htaccess, which already includes some edits for mod_rewrite and CSP. CORS is handled by Laravel middleware.

Comment: Can you opt out of http/2? If not you can try in your export route to basically figure out the size (in bytes) of the file you are sending and trying to set the `Content-Length` header manually. If it ends up being 0 again then something must be overriding it somewhere.

Comment: Tried this https://stackoverflow.com/a/46501113/542191 to turn off the http/2 via htaccess. Didn't work out. Trying to figure out further

Comment: Sidenote, htaccess is for apache as far as I know. nginx has its site configuration in a different location (normally /etc/nginx/sites-enabled)

Comment: It seems to work though